Swipe feed via Selenium Python (hold and drag, no scrolling)
My goal is to make Selenium working with feed that doesn't react on scroll or on any keyboard keys. I need to scroll using this actions: press and hold, drag to top, release
I've tried to fix it using
actions.move_to_element(element) \
    .click_and_hold() \
    .move_by_offset(0, -100) \
    .release() \
    .perform()

But I've had a problem with it: my python just stuck, it was trying to do something eternally, without any errors or smth.
Also I tried generated js code, but it said that element is not clickable. (via  MouseEvent).
The code is working in --headless=new mode, so we can't use gui or something else.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
